# Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, gtk

I am running ubuntu 15.10.
I am trying to execute a java GUI program under eclipse that imports a ton of libraries including javafx and google map libraries.

The java program fails to execute and gives the error:

Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"

I have googled the error message " Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module" " - but none of the solutions I have found on stackoverflow or through google appear to work for me.

Any ideas on how to diagnose and fix this error?

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get-install unity-gtk3-module` fix the problem? If not, try `apt-cache search unity-gtk-module` (which suggests that there is also an `unity-gtk2-module`). What program are you trying to run? From where did you obtain it? And have you satisfied its' *dependencies*?

Comment: I tried sudo apt-get install unity-gtk3-module - command response is that unity-gtk3-module is already latest version.

Comment: Do not know what the apt-cache search command does.  It returns the following information:  unity-gtk-module-common - Common files for GtkMenuShell D-Bus exporter
unity-gtk-module-autopilot - GtkMenuShell D-Bus Autopilot tests

Comment: I got the java file from a Coursera course.  This file is the starter code I need for assignments - so do not have control over java libraries.  Its a mapping GUI using google map libraries and also javafx.  The course developers do not give information on dependencies or specify any specific OS.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error running java starter code for a Coursera course in Eclipse.  I noticed errors in the java code - java error was "Lambda expressions are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above".  I am using 1.8 JDK.  Problem was that Java Compiler compliance level was set to 1.7 for the project in eclipse.  I changed the compliance level to 1.8 and program ran without error.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install unity-gtk2-module:i386
```

Solved it for me. (Note: I was running x86 app on x64 system.)

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for my Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt install unity-gtk3-module
```

My case is that even running emacs would trig that warning.